# Javascript reserved words?

Tags: javascript

I have some JS code which generates the following object,

```
return {
    "type": "some thing",
    "width": 2,
    "colour": "#AA12BB",
    "values": [2,3,4]
}
```

The creation of this isn't a problem.

In writing the test for the method that returns this am having a problem accessing the width/type attributes: the following assertions fail (it leads to a execution/syntax error, which go away when i comment them).

```
assertEquals('some thing', jsonObj.type);
assertEquals(2, jsonObj.width);
```

while

```
assertEquals('#AA12BB', jsonObj.colour);
```

passes

Since I cannot change the key names for what I am doing, is there any way to access these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
assertEquals('some thing', jsonObj["type"]);
assertEquals(2, jsonObj["width"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example works fine for me. ‘width’ and ‘type’ are *not* reserved words in JavaScript (although ‘typeof’ is).

Comment: Weird.. you are right about them not being reserved words... But for whatever reason on FF3.0.6 it failed for me.. CSS? Firebug? Hmm, not sure

Answer (score 0):

dot notation does not work with reserved words, such as "type".  In that case you have to use array notation.

Mozilla's list of [Java Script Reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words).

Comment: Type doesn't appear to be a reserved word, but this is the correct way to access those properties.